# ERROR: Invalid psql argument: must be full path to a file named psql

Tags: windows, monitoring, psql, nagios, bucardo

i try to monitor postgres 13 on windows 10 with the script check_postgres.pl of https://bucardo.org/downloads/check_postgres.pl.html#development.

I have this error

> ERROR: Invalid argument: must be full path to a file nomed psql`

however, I did modify the variable `$NO_PSQL_OPTION= 0` and I defined the path on the psql variable like this

```
$opt{PSQL}="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"
```

Comment: `"C:Program FilesPostgreSQL\13\bin"` should probably be `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"` or maybe the backslashes need esacping: `"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\13\\bin"` not sure what `PSQL` should point to, but if that is used to find the `psql.exe` then this should also be included, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\psql.exe"`

Comment: yes i will  correct the path for the post. yes PSQL point for this path

Comment: i try whit `"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\13\\bin"` @a_horse_with_no_name but it is the same